# How to fixing error path npm on windows 10

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Have done a lot of googling, tried reinstalling node.js using the official installer, but my **npm** pathing still doesn't work.

This doesn't work

```
npm install foo
```

I get an error message saying missing module npm-cli.js

2 hours of googling later I discovered a workaround
Instead of simply '**npm**' I type

```
node C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
```

But how can I correct my NodeJS install so I can simply type 'npm' ?